# What is the meaning of "the last train"?

Tags: word-usage

"the last train"

Could this mean either of "the previous train" or "the opposite of the first train" depending on the context?

I'm sometimes confused with the meaning of "last", such as "the last order" and "the last train".

Comment: The last train of the evening that will take me home - the last train that left a station which is now disused - the last (previous) train before this one.

Comment: The word 'last' can often be ambiguous, yes. You could use 'previous' or 'final' to remove doubt, if the context doesn't make it clear. "The last train today" clearly does not mean 'previous', nor does "I got on the last train to London".

Comment: In the 1966 song by The Monkees, the ambiguity surrounding the word "last" is resolved by the context. Clearly you can't take a train that has already left, so it must mean the final train.
   Take the last train to Clarksville
   And I'll meet you at the station

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the meaning can be resolved by the context.

If describing the future, it will normally mean "the last possible train" **(a)** - usually the last departure of the day (occasionally, the last ever **(b)** - e.g. if a station is to be closed):

- "I must go now - the last train home leaves in ten minutes." **(a)**
- "The last train from Mornington East will be on 25th July." **(b)**

For the past, it will usually mean most recent **(c)**, but could mean the last train of a previous day **(d)**:

- "He left on the last train from Platform 1 - I think that was to Helmston." **(c)**
- "The last train from Mornington West was in 1964." **(d)**
- "I had to share with half a dozen drunks on the last train yesterday." **(c)**